# Issue connecting device with Azure Iot central

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-central, azure-iot-suite

i have issues connecting my device with Azure Iot central because my device's password have 64 characters and the minimum for Azure Iot central is 90, what can i do? use another Azure Iot service or I can change that condition in the Azure Iot central.

I'm new with Iot.

Comment: Please show your code and more detail of what you are trying to do.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could you please let us know the document you have referred? We see the same question being asked on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/36159/limits-connecting-with-my-device.html)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thx everyone i already solved the issue, the documentation was ok

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [Get connected to Azure IoT Central](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-get-connected)

This article describes about the options for connecting your devices to an Azure IoT Central application.

To secure the communication between a device and your application, IoT Central supports both shared access signatures (SAS) and X.509 certificates.

This article describes the following use cases:

- [Connect a single device using SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-get-connected#connect-a-single-device)
- [Connect devices at scale using SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-get-connected#connect-devices-at-scale-using-sas)
- [Connect devices at scale using X.509 certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-get-connected#connect-devices-using-x509-certificates) - **the
  recommended approach for production environments.**
- [Connect devices without first registering them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-get-connected#connect-without-registering-devices)
- [Connect devices that use DPS individual enrollments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-get-connected#individual-enrollment-based-device-connectivity)
- [Automatically associate a device with a device template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-get-connected#automatically-associate-with-a-device-template)

Please share your use-case along with any error logs or screenshots to better understand your scenario and help you further.

The same question can be found at [Microsoft's Q&A forum.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/36159/index.html)